# XenServer 6.5 host is not passing through network traffic (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, xenserver

I have recently install XenServer 6.5 and have 5 static IP addresses assigned to the server, the host however is not passing through the VM traffic across the assigned IP, it is defaulting the additional IP directly to the host, for instance:

- 192.168.1.1 (Host IP)
- 192.168.1.2 (Additional IP) - Navigating to this goes to the same destination as 192.168.1.1 in the browser, ie. The links to download XenCenter

The Host has the following network configuration:

- IP: 192.168.1.1
- Subnet: 255.255.255.248
- Gateway: 192.168.1.100

I have added 192.168.1.2 to NIC0 (which is the active NIC) and then configured it in Ubuntu. It has the following properties, along with an auto-generated MAC address by XenServer.

- IP: 192.168.1.2
- Subnet: 255.255.255.248
- Gateway: 192.168.1.100 (I have also tried with 192.168.1.1)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host just need one member IP for management. All xen management traffic will go there.

If you need more bandwidth the supported way to do that is to **bond** your NIC. Thus 4 NIC will become one or two NIC become one, you see the concept, but it will still be only one IP for that bond

Whats your goal there ?

Comment: I only want to use 1 IP for management, but if I create another network and assign an IP to it (using the active NIC), the traffic just goes to the host from the new IP. I'm unable to add an IP that goes to a VM rather than the host

Comment: @ah1 I its just a small design error then, If management nic got an ip of like 192.168.1.1, if a server with a ip 10.0.0.5 want to talk to it, its the router do the job. If the network are not routed, you add a second nic that is part of rhe 192.* network to that server that got a 10.0.0.5 ip. Please check your switch connectiin versus the host, you can update the question with a network plan drawing.

Comment: I'm getting the network team to check, but I think it's XenServer. Say 192.168.1.1 is the management IP which when navigated to hits the links to download XenCenter, when I add 192.168.1.2 as an IP for the VM and create a new network for it, add the IP to that network on the same live NIC, then 192.168.1.2 points to the host rather than the VM. I'm getting a network topology at the moment

Comment: @ah1 ok, in that vm you assign it the same nic as the management? like nic0 is management ?

Comment: I have the following: https://imgur.com/a/5GLQV - I have the VM-1 IP assigned to the VM running Ubuntu. .130 is the host, .129 is the gateway and .131 is the addon IP.

Comment: @ah1 I see two error. Network 1 is setup untagged but I see the vm-1 tagged as 1 for the Vlan. Second point, assign vm-1 to network 1 please, but dont set the vm ip there, it must be set inside the vm (in ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks - I'm unable to tag Network 1 - there's no option to. I've removed the VM1 IP address from the 'IP Address Configuration' section so only the management IP is there and I've set it within Ubuntu. I'm not sure what you mean by assigning VM-1 to Network 1? They are both on NIC1

Comment: @ah1 yes, its what I meant, both assigned to nic1. Now if the xen guest tool is installed in ubuntu the host will list the vm ip, but in the vm info tab

Comment: Ah, I have them that way, and the IP is being shown in the networking section on the VM as xentools is installed, however the IP address (.131) is unreachable - https://imgur.com/a/MvtVo

Comment: @ah1 vm-1 in the network tab should not be on VLAN 1

Comment: Okay, thanks. It says that it must be assigned to a VLAN, so I put it to 0, re-added to the server and rebooted the network (eth0) and stillno luck pinging the VM or going from inside the VM to the outside world

Comment: @ah1 Then just delete that, as usually in that tab its to define your VLAN, I dont know why your vm is tagged there. Make sure in the VM tab its assigned to Network 1.